# Swift: Make UILabel height equivalent to height of text

Tags: swift, xcode, uilabel, constraints

I am wondering how to adjust the height of a UILabel to match the text. I want the label's fontsize to adjust to fit the width of the device while keeping the height snug.

Thus far, I have it set to 2 lines and my altering code is simply:

```
 welcomeLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
 welcomeLabel.sizeToFit()
 welcomeLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
```

The red background is solely to display the issue with the height.

[Photo of issue with label background red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDVgf.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just set the number of lines to "0", either on your code or in the "attribute inspector", and don't give it any height.

```
welcomeLabel.numberOfLines = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. If I do that, I get W \n elc filling the entirety of the screen. Constraints are 20 trailing and leading and then a 57 to top.

Comment: Well, in this case set the number of lines to "1", and in the "attribute inspector" set the "Autoshrink" to "minimum font scale". this will scale the font size down if needed. Also you can set the scale between 1-0